# Data Cardinality keras odd number of images- train test split

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, valueerror, train-test-split

My autoencoder shows a "Valueerror:  Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 14
y sizes: 31
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."

```
split_size_i = int(images.shape[0]*0.7)
split_size = int(images_gray.shape[0]*0.7)

autoencoder.fit(images[split_size_i:], images[:split_size_i], 
                epochs=10, 
                shuffle=True, 
                validation_data=(images_gray[split_size:],images_gray[:split_size]))
```

My dataset for images and images_gray has 45 images each. Need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states x has 14 images and y has 31 images, both x and y must be equal.

Doing the following changes will help in solving the error

```
autoencoder.fit(images_gray[:split_size], images[:split_size_i], 
                epochs=10, 
                shuffle=True, 
                validation_data=(images_gray[split_size:],images[split_size_i:]))
```

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!